# Клавиатура inline и отправка файла Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Как корректно реализовать отправку файла?
Ниже многоуровневое меню, сами кнопки нет смысла отправлять.
Проблема в нижней части представленного кода:
При нажатии кнопки, пользователю отправляется файл и он отображается ниже инлайн клавиатуры, а сама кнопка долго горит, как будто не может обработать событие.
Не могу сообразить, как это облагородить. Пробовал возвращать клавиатуру `reply_markup=nav.menu_tizer` - не получается. Она появляется, но не работает.
Как после отправки файла повторно вывести клавиатуру?

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def menu_info(call):
    if call.data == "btn_back":
        await bot.edit_message_text("Главное меню:", call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=nav.main_menu)
    elif call.data == "btn_back2":
        await bot.edit_message_text("Выбери нужный раздел:", call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=nav.menu_educ)
    elif call.data == "btn_conn":
        await bot.edit_message_text("Выбери удобный способ связи:", call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=nav.menu_info)
    elif call.data == "btn_cons":
        await bot.edit_message_text("Выбери нужный раздел:", call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=nav.menu_conult)
        # Обновили флаг в бд для консультаций
        db.user_consultation(user_id_global)
    elif call.data == "btn_educ":
        await bot.edit_message_text("Выбери нужный раздел:", call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=nav.menu_educ)
    elif call.data == "btn_tizer":
        await bot.edit_message_text("Получи бесплатный урок:", call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=nav.menu_tizer)
        # Обновили флаг в бд для обучения
        db.user_education(user_id_global)
    elif call.data == "btn_pdf":
        file_pdf = open('./Guide.pdf', 'rb')
        await bot.send_document(call.message.chat.id, file_pdf, caption="Сохраните файл")
    else:
        pass
```

[image: Пример]